# I can't deploy node app. Heroku give me this error

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

When i deployed node app to heroku, i get this error

```
2022-02-13T12:58:57.962105+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
2022-02-13T12:58:59.965280+00:00 app[web.1]: [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Comment: in heroku, I think redis is no longer on 127.0.0.1. you need to set a redis_url. check config vars on heroku for redis url

Comment: vicki is almost right, but you normally wouldn't _set_ `REDIS_URL`. You'd provision an addon and let _it_ set that value. Then you just use it in your code.